# How to display data/predict_sample.tensor.json as image?

Tags: json, tensorflow, google-cloud-ml

I'm going through the [Prediction Quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/ml/docs/quickstarts/prediction) for Google Cloud ML.  I'm done training the model and ran a prediction and got the expected output.  How do I see the contents of data/predict_sample.tensor.json , the sample input  used at https://cloud.google.com/ml/docs/quickstarts/prediction

I've seen tensorflow related posts for decoding/encoding png/jpeg.  But this file is a json file. To make it easy to curl, I shared the sample at https://storage.googleapis.com/darianhickmancom-ml/mnist_deployable_darianhickman_20161117_231714/sample_images/predict_sample.tensor.json

Answer (score 0):

I guess that just each image is a pixel intensity, written row by row. To show it, you can do:

```
import json
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

f = open('image.json', 'r')
for desc in f.readlines():
   obj = json.loads(desc)
   im = np.array(obj['image']).reshape(28, 28)
   plt.imshow(1 - im, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
   plt.show()
```

The first image looks like this:
[image: mnist-digit]